# Connecting emacs to package archives

Tags: ruby, macos, emacs

I'm new to emacs and seeing if I like the ruby-emacs ecosystem. I'm trying to follow these instructions: https://lorefnon.me/2014/02/02/configuring-emacs-for-rails.html but, I can't seem to get the package archives working. I am using GNU Emacs 25.3.1. My ~./emacs file is blank other than what is first suggested by that website:

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives 
             '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)
```

The trouble is when I try to package install, `flymake-ruby` is not suggested nor available. Other packages are though like `flymake-rust`.
Any ideas of what to check would be super. When installing `flymake-rust` Emacs does alter my `~/.emacs` file so that seems to be fine. On OS X.

Answer (score 1):

Melpa's URL has changed to "http://melpa.org/packages/".